# Calling standard contact Seibel Business Service from Java application

Tags: java

I want to call the standard "Contact" Seibel Business Service from my java program. I will appreciate if you can point me to some resources on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are bunch of documentation and samples online.
You need to replace the Echo service by the Contact service.
I post just an example from [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/EAI3/EAI3_IntegJava3.html) below:

> Aside from the business object and business component API, the primary
>   point of integration with the Siebel application is by using business
>   services. There are several ways to invoke a business service. The
>   simplest way is using the Siebel Java Data Bean directly, as shown in
>   the following example. 
>   Alternatively, Siebel Tools provides a Code
>   Generator which creates, for any business service, Java classes that
>   invoke the business service. The generated code may invoke the
>   business service either using the Siebel Java Data Bean or using the
>   Siebel Resource Adapter. The creation and use of generated code is
>   described in the next section. The Siebel Resource Adapter is part of
>   the Java EE Connector Architecture, which is described in About the
>   Siebel Resource Adapter. The following is an example of invoking a
>   business service directly using the Siebel Java Data Bean.

```
    import com.siebel.data.SiebelException;
    import com.siebel.data.SiebelPropertySet;
    import com.siebel.data.SiebelService;

    public class BasicDataBeanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SiebelException {

        SiebelDataBean dataBean = new SiebelDataBean();
        dataBean.login("siebel://mymachine:2321/siebel/SCCObjMgr_enu", "USER", "PWD", "enu");

        SiebelService businessService = dataBean.getService("Workflow Utilities");
        SiebelPropertySet input = new SiebelPropertySet();
        SiebelPropertySet output = new SiebelPropertySet();
        input.setValue("Please echo this");

        businessService.invokeMethod("Echo", input, output);

        System.out.println("Output: " + output.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped